# Sentiment Analysis with word embeddings using Keras Embedding Layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, sentiment-analysis, embedding, word-embedding

I need a little bit of clarification regarding my model results.

**Here is my use case:**

- Deciding whether a review from a company from S&P 500 is negative or positive. I used a crawled data set from indeed. (The dataset was labelled (0 - positive, 1 - negative), tokenized and cleaned).

Here are some important information, in order to understand the model and my approach:

```
# Constants
NB_WORDS = 44000  # Parameter indicating the number of words we'll put in the dictionary
VAL_SIZE = 1000  # Size of the validation set
NB_START_EPOCHS = 10  # Number of epochs we usually start to train with
EPOCH_ITER = list(range(0,11)) # For stepwise evaluating the accuracy metrics for 10 epochs
BATCH_SIZE = 512  # Size of the batches used in the mini-batch gradient descent
MAX_LEN = 267  # Maximum number of words in a sequence (review)
REV_DIM = 300 # Number of dimensions of the indeed review word embeddings --> most common Mikolow et al., 2013


# Modeling
emb_model = models.Sequential()

emb_model.add(layers.Embedding(NB_WORDS, REV_DIM, input_length=MAX_LEN)) 
# Embedding layer is first hidden layer

"""
Embedding Layer (
input_length = no. of words in vocabularly;
output_dim = dimensionality; 
max_length = length of largest review
)
"""
                                                                            
emb_model.add(layers.Flatten()) 
# Flatten Layers are reshaping tensor to 1-D array

emb_model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
# Is the regular deeply connected neural network layer. It is most common and 
# frequently used layer. Dense layer does the below operation on the input and return the output.
# Operation := output = activation(dot(input, kernel) + bias)
# further see: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/keras/keras_dense_layer.htm#:~:text=Advertisements,input%20and%20return%20the%20output.
# Defines the output size in our case 2, hence positive or negative (0 or 1)

emb_model.summary()
```

I already did some interpretation. But since I'm a beginner, I really need further information/interpretations/tips, especially on how and why to improve my model.

**Here are my results:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can try using LSTMs or 1D Convolutions to learn temporal features from the text.

Comment: One way to increase accuracy by adding dropout and pooling layer in your model. Which will reduce the dimension and noise/distortion. Thanks!